# Prevent access to php file in browser

Tags: php, linux

I am using linux box and php. I have many cron tasks scheduled. I want to prevent access to these files if some one directly tries to access these files using browser. How do i do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sample solution using **.htaccess**:

```
<Files "cronjobs.php">
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from allowedmachine.com
  Allow from localhost
  Deny from all
</Files>
```

Comment: Shouldn't this say 'cronjobs' ?

Answer (score 3):

- Don't place the files under the web root
- Require authentication/authorization
- Limit access via IP address

Comment: A suggestion for authentication/authorization would be htaccess.

Comment: "Require authentication/authorization" then cron can run it?

Comment: @Akam — So long as cron passes a set of valid credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this? [source]: https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/.htaccess

```
# "-Indexes" will have Apache block users from browsing folders without a
# default document Usually you should leave this activated, because you
# shouldn't allow everybody to surf through every folder on your server (which
# includes rather private places like CMS system folders).
<IfModule mod_autoindex.c>
  Options -Indexes
</IfModule>
```